# help in field calculator

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1

In Arcmap (10.1 version)
I create a new field call "gender", and i want the content of "gender" will be changed according to others fields. For example, if a word(boy) is shown in a field call "person" in one row, then the content of "gender" will also change to boy (replace the original content).

Here are my code(VB script):

```
IF [personA] = "boy" and [personB] = "boy" THEN
    [gender] = "boy,boy"
EndIF

IF  [personA] <> "boy"  THEN
    [gender] = "Non-boy,boy"
EndIF

IF  [personB] <> "boy"  THEN
    [gender] = "boy,Non-boy"
EndIF
```

however, it cannot run and a message was shown.

```
A field name was not found or there were unbalanced quotation marks.
ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
Item not found in this collection.
Failed to execute (Calculate Field).
```

Comment: Your script assumes that each statement builds on the last.  Unfortunately, the way the code is set up, each block is evaluated on it's own.  You really need to nest some if-else statements to cover all four of your potential outcomes (boy, boy; boy, Non-boy; Non-boy, boy; Non-boy, Non-boy)

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better served to nest your If Else statements.  I'm more comfortable using Python, but here is a working example:

[image]

```
def reclass(PersonA, PersonB):
    if PersonA == "boy":
        if PersonB == "boy":
            output = "boy, boy"
        else:
            output = "boy, Non-boy"
    else:
        if PersonB == "boy":
            output = "Non-boy, boy"
        else:
            output = "Non-boy, Non-boy"
return output


Gender = reclass(!PersonA!, !PersonB!)
```